# How to make Image move in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiimageview, touch

I have an `UIImageView` which covers all of my screen. The pictures that I'm displaying are bigger than it and the `.contentmode` is set to the`.scaleAspectFill` So the `UImageView` is just showing a cropped version of each picture.
In front of them is a `CollectionViewController` which consists
of multiple pages.
I've used `scrollViewWillEndDragging` to change my background picture when I move through the pages with a short animation ( each page has a specific background).

Please Help on:
How can I make the background picture move with my touch move horizontally until the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` happens and move back to its original position if the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` didn't happen.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can use UICollectionView, with pagingEnabled.

Comment: It is already enabled and I'm using it. I need to move the background with each paging act.